# Matplotlib Table Coordinates and plt.show()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a rectangular patch relative to the coordinates of a Matplotlib table, below is my minimal reproducible example. In comments I have put the output of the respective method calls.

```
# Python 3.8.5
# Numpy 1.19.1
# Pandas 1.1.1
# Matplotlib 3.3.1

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

test_array = np.array(range(0,77)).reshape((7,11))
pt = pd.DataFrame(test_array, index=['AAA', 'AA', 'A', 'BBB', 'BB', 'B', 'CCC'])

data = pt.values.ravel().tolist()
data = np.array(['{:.1f}%'.format(i * 100).replace('nan%', '') for i in data]).reshape(pt.shape).tolist()
row_label = pt.index.tolist()
column_label = ['{:.0f}'.format(i) for i in pt.columns.tolist()]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
table = ax.table(cellText=data, rowLabels=row_label, colLabels=column_label,
                 bbox=(0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 0.3))
for key, cell in table.get_celld().items():
    # Remove cell border
    cell.set_linewidth(0)
    # Change font weight
    if key[0] == 0 or key[1] == -1:
        cell.set_text_props(fontweight='bold')
    # Change cell colors
    else:
        if key[1] == 0:
            cell.set_facecolor('red')
        elif key[1] == 1:
            cell.set_facecolor('orange')
        elif key[1] in (2, 3, 4):
            cell.set_facecolor('yellow')
        elif key[1] > 4:
            cell.set_facecolor('green')
ax.add_patch(Rectangle(table[(0, 0)].get_xy(), 0.3, 0.3))
table[(0, 0)].get_xy()
# (0, 0)
fig.canvas.draw()
table[(0, 0)].get_xy()
# (0.16879032258064516, 0.4625)
plt.show()
table[(0, 0)].get_xy()
# (0.2, 0.4625000000000001)
```

Before calling `plt.show()`, the coordinates of the table seem to be (0, 0) based on the output of `table[(0, 0)].get_xy()`. After calling `plt.show()`, the coordinates seem to be the correct coordinates of the first cell of the table. A prior call of `fig.canvas.draw()`, gives another x-coordinate.

How can I get the correct coordinates without calling `plt.show()` so that I can add the patch at the correct location? Is this expected behaviour? I understand that it must have to do with how the canvas is created, but I do not understand the inner workings and would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Have you solved this? I am having the same problem.

Comment: I have found that `table[(i, j)].get_xy()` always return `(0, 0)` contrary to what the doc says. I believe this is a bug.